# Find total number of assignment in the worst case?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have this algorithm

```
Algorithm (A[1..n])
    for i <- 1 to n do
        if (A[i] < 0) then
            A[i] <- 1 * A[i]
        End if
    End for
```

I have to find the total number of assignment in the worst case, but I'm a little bit confused, do I say I have 2 or 1, one for the assign A[i] in the statement and second for the i in the for loop (i <- 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the question is asking you to focus on line 4, in which you assign a value to A[i]. You can also focus on the for-loop with and its control variable to get a complete answer, but the only way to know for sure is to ask the person responsible for the problem.

Anyway, more precisely, the question is how many assignments do you do in the worst case as a function of the array length $n$. As you can see, this number is determined by the number of times the preceding if-branch evaluates to true. Your task is to argue how many times that can happen in the worst case.